# Mysql Select find third week and day of week from table date

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL select query that I am trying to get the third Thursday from a date in my table here is what I have for the query any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
trandate,
transno,
inputdate,
DATE_ADD(DATE(trandate),
    INTERVAL (IF(DAYOFWEEK(trandate) < 5,
        (3 + WEEK(trandate)),
        WEEK(trandate))) DAY) AS third_thursday
FROM
    ts.debtortrans
WHERE
    trandate = '2019-03-01';
```

Comment: Do you mean the third Thursday after the date, or the third Thursday of the month that the date is in?

Comment: What are your cases for if day of week < Thursday, = Thursday and > Thurday. Maybe some sample dates and what they map to would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the third Thursday after the date, you can get that by adding 3 weeks, then a number of days to adjust the date to a Thursday. This is computed using

```
(12 - DAYOFWEEK(trandate)) % 7
```

We need to use 12 rather than 5 ([`DAYOFWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) for Thursday) as MySQL returns a negative number for a modulo operation where the dividend operand is negative.

So the formula is

```
trandate + INTERVAL 3 WEEK + INTERVAL ((12 - DAYOFWEEK(trandate)) % 7) DAY
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72295e7359dec01bbe85acecfbbc844c)